# How to get value of node which is selected in Tree jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div which shows a tree in it. I want to get the value of the item selected in tree. But i am unable to get the value of it i am attaching a sample code.
Also this tree is added to the div dynamically.

```
<div id="listMergefile">
  <ul class="jqueryFileTree">
    <li class="file ext_pdf">
      <a rel="/dssd/.pdf" class="FontClass" href="">
   </a>
  </li>
     <li class="file ext_rep">
     <a rel="/Expressions (2) 2014-26-08.repdocument" class="FontClass" href="">
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the value"?

Comment: I want rel attribute value. for example:rel="/Expressions (2) 2014-26-08.repdocument"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it - http://jsfiddle.net/07tm0v5o/

```
$('li').mouseover(function(){
    var relValue = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
    var relSpan = '<span class="relValue">' + relValue + '</span>';
    $(this).append(relSpan);
});
$('li').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('.relValue').remove();
});
```

The principal is the same regardless of how you'll be viewing the data.

Comment: Thanks @jay Blanchard. Its really helped me